# Rails - multiple theads to avoid the slack 3 second API response rule

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, slack-api

I am working with the slack API. My script does a bunch of external processing and in some cases it can take around 3-6 seconds. What is happening is the Slack API expects a 200 response within 3 seconds and because my function is not finished within 3 seconds, it retries again and then it ends up posting the same automated responses 2-3 times.

I confirmed this by commenting out all the functions and I had no issue, it posted the responses to slack fine. I then added sleep 10 and it done the same responses 3 times so the ohly thing different was it took longer.

From what I read, I need to have threaded responses. I then need to first respond to the slack API in thread 1 and then go about processing my functions.

Here is what I tried:

```
def events
  Thread.new do
    json = {
      "text": "Here is your 200 response immediately slack",
    }
    render(json: json)
  end
    
  puts "--------------------------------Json response started----------------------"
  sleep 30
  puts "--------------------------------Json response completed----------------------"
  puts "this is a successful response"
end
```

When I tested it the same issue happened so I tried using an online API tester and it hits the page, waits 30 seconds and then returns the 200 response but I need it to respond immediately with the 200, THEN process the rest otherwise I will get duplicates.

Am I using threads properly or is there another way to get around this Slack API 3 second response limit? I am new to both rails and slack API so a bit lost here.

Appreciate the eyes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using [ActionJob](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html) to run the code in the background if you don't need to use the result of the code in the response. First, create an ActiveJob job by running:

```
bin/rails generate job do_stuff
```

And then open up the file created in `app/jobs/do_stuff_job.rb` and edit the `#perform` function to include your code (so the `puts` statements and `sleep 30` in your example). Finally, from the controller action you can call `DoStuff.perform_later` and your job will run in the background! Your final controller action will look something like this:

```
def events
  DoStuff.perform_later # this schedules DoStuff to be done later, in
                        # the background, so it will return immediately
                        # and continue to the next line.
  json = {
    "text": "Here is your 200 response immediately slack",
  }
  render(json: json)
end
```

---

> As an aside, I'd highly recommend never using `Thread.new` in rails. It can create some really confusing behavior especially in test scripts for a number of reasons, but usually because of how it interacts with open connections and specifically ActiveRecord.

Comment: Wow, impressive how easy that was to do, was expecting a huge task to get around this. Love this language and thanks a million for the clear explation.

Comment: np! glad I could be helpful :)